How to generate the netconf configuration for traffic enginerring with Segment routing from the CLI commands on Cisco IOS XR platofrm
I have below configurations to be pushed via netconf :
Router Type :- IOS -XR
CLI :-
segment-routing
 traffic-eng
  segment-list ar4.BLB_ar7.BLB_c_10000_ep_1.2.3.4
   index 1 mpls label 24001
   index 2 mpls label 24017
   index 3 mpls label 24276
   index 4 mpls label 24006
   index 5 mpls label 24254
   index 6 mpls label 24012
  !
  policy ar4.BLB_ar7.BLB_c_10000_ep_1.2.3.4
   color 10000 end-point ipv4 1.2.3.4
   candidate-paths
    preference 100
     explicit segment-list ar4.BLB_ar7.BLB_c_10000_ep_1.2.3.4
     !
    !
   !
  !
 !
!

